# How is this is an identity?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions, rational-functions

So we have started studying partial fractions.The book teaches two methods:

1. By equating coefficients
2. By utilizing the fact that when a rational fraction is decomposed to partial fractions it is an identity

I cannot quite understand how does the 2nd method works.If we make the denominator of one of the fractions zero , it would become undefined , so how will it be an identity then???
Thanks in Advance.

---

For example, take the following
$$
\frac{1}{(x+3)(x+4)}=\frac{a}{(x+3)} + \frac{b}{(x+4)}
$$

so if we put $x=-3$ then the left hand side of the equation would become undefined.

Also on the right hand side the term $\frac{a}{(x+3)}$ would also become undefined, so how would this equation be an identity?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Perhaps by providing at least one instance?

Comment: The term you say is undefined actually isn't in this equation. Rather than plugging in, you need to first multiply all the terms by the full polynomial. That way there will be evident that there is no indetermination.

Comment: Hmm... let me address this indirectly. Are you familiar with the form of the trigonometric Pythagorean identity $1+ \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$ ? It's not defined for all $x$, but where it *is* defined, it always holds.

Answer (score 2):

It's an identity for values of x were the fraction is defined.  Both sides are defined for the same x and undefined for the same x.  And both sides are equal when they are defined.  Thus it's an equality.

This is only a problem if one side is defined for a value of x while the other side isn't, or if there are any values of x where the two sides aren't equal.  That is not the case, so there is no problem.

Comment: so are you saying that if one term on side is undefined and another term on the other side is also undefined , so the equality still holds ?

Comment: Yes.  As long as both sides are define and undefined for the exact same values of x.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we have some polynomial in the denominator. For simplicity and for you to be able to understand better, let's give it the following form:

$$
\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)...(x-d)(x-e)}.
$$

We can then propose *another* form for this expression. We propose that it looks like the following:

$$
\frac{A}{(x-a)} + \frac{B}{(x-a)} + … + \frac{D}{(x-d)} + \frac{E}{(x-e)}.
$$

We say that they are the same thing, different representations, right? Then we can equate!

$$
\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)...(x-d)(x-e)} =
\frac{A}{(x-a)} + \frac{B}{(x-b)} + … + \frac{D}{(x-d)} + \frac{E}{(x-e)}.
$$

Now multiply both sides by the original factorized polynomial and we get

$$
\scriptsize{
1 = A(x-b) … (x-d)(x-e) + B(x-a) … (x-d)(x-e) + … + D(x-a)(x-b) … (x-e) + E(x-a)(x-b).
}
$$

Finally, if we plug in very special values for $x$, then we can completely eliminate one term. And we can do this exactly as many times as there are terms. In the end a system of equations remains with the values of the coefficients that go above each term in the partial fraction representation. Cool, right?

Comment: but if we dont reduce the fractions to simple terms , then will it still be an identity

Comment: still cant understand please please if you could elaborate further? thanks

Comment: @Batwayne The moment we decided to make an alternative representation of the quotient we said "it is an identity". The interesting thing is that proposing a function of the form of partial fractions works very neatly for polynomials. Does $\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{A}{x-1}$ not work? Which value would you does $A$ *have*, not give, to discover the real form? When you write that in partial fractions, the coefficients aren't variable; they are already fixed and determined but we don't know them yet.

Comment: but i am having problem with the fact in my original post if 1/(x+3)(x+4)=a/(x+3)+b/(x+4) denominator on the left hand side becomes zero by plugging in x=-3 then would not the equation become: ∞ = ∞ +b ? then how would it  still be an equation ?

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Fractions** : Steps

**Step (1)** Check the degrees of both **numerator (n)** and **denominator (d)** separately.

**(i)**  If $n<d$ follow step **(2)**

**(ii)** If $n \geq d$ Add a polynomial of degree $(n-d)$, and follow **(2)**

Ex : $\frac{x^2}{x^3+1} \Rightarrow 2<3 \Rightarrow $ follow step **(2)**

Ex: $\frac{x^3+x+1}{x^3-2x-1} \Rightarrow 3=3 \Rightarrow \frac{x^3+x+1}{x^3-2x-1} =A+ $ .....follow step **(2)**

Ex: $\frac{3x^4+x^2+1}{3x^3-2x+1} \Rightarrow 4>3\Rightarrow \frac{3x^4+x^2+1}{3x^3-2x+1} =Ax+B+ $ ......follow step **(2)**

Ex: $\frac{x^5+x+1}{3x^3-2x+1} \Rightarrow 5>3\Rightarrow \frac{x^5+x+1}{3x^3-2x+1} =Ax^2+Bx+C +$ .......follow step **(2)**

**Step (2)** : **Factorize** the denominator and write each factor separately with a numerator of degree less than one with respect to the chosen factor.

Ex: $\frac{x^5+x+1}{3x^3-2x+1} \Rightarrow 5>3\Rightarrow \frac{x^5+x+1}{3x^3-2x+1} =\frac{x^5+x+1}{(x+1)(3x^2-3x+1)} =Ax^2+Bx+C + \frac {D}{(x+1)}+ \frac{Ex+F}{(3x^2-3x+1)}$

**Step (3)** : Now find $A,B,C,D,E,F$ by multiplying whole expression by $(x+1)(3x^2-3x+1)$ . **You could use $x=-1$ to find constants and compare co-efficients.**

**Important Ex:**

$1) \frac{x}{(x+1)^3} = \frac {A}{(x+1)}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac {C}{(x+1)^3}$

$2) \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^3} = \frac {Ax+B}{(x^2+1)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac {Ex+F}{(x^2+1)^3}$